# What board games have maps that change each time?

Tags: game-design, recommendations, mechanics

I'm designing a board game
Each time the game is played, the board must change and also be revealed as player pieces scout the edges of the known map
Can anybody name other board games with similar mechanics that I can study for ideas?

Answer (score 4):

On BoardGameGeek there are listings for two mechanisms that are likely to help - over 7,000 games are listed under [Modular Board](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2011/modular-board), and 166 under [Map Addition](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2959/map-addition).

Answer (score 3):

[Betrayal at House on the Hill](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10547/betrayal-house-hill) is a pretty perfect fit for that description - as players open the doors of the house for the first time, rooms are added from the stack, randomising the layout of the house every game

Comment: As my game is in a supernatural attic that does sound like it fits the bill, thanks!